# Object arguments with the same keys in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that accepts two objects and returns a merged result. The difference between this function and a common `merge` or splat operator is that this function has to accept and return objects with the same set of keys. For the sake of simplicity lets assume only flat objects.

I was able to come up with a version that has compile checks for inputs.
But, for some reason, it does not protect the output from injecting extra keys:

```
function strictMerge<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  o1 : {[K in keyof T] : unknown},
  o2 : {[K in keyof T] : unknown},
) : {[K in keyof T] : unknown} {
  return {...o1, ...o2, bad: "bad"} // <-- no compile error :(
}

const o1 = strictMerge({}, {a: "a"})       // <-- compile error :)
const o2 = strictMerge({}, {})             // <-- no compile error :)
const o1 = strictMerge({a: "a"}, {a: "b"}) // <-- no compile error :)
```

Is it some known TypeScript limitation? Is there a way to enforce the rule in question? How would you model the same function without `unknown`s?

Update: i'm interested only in typings here, not the algorithm. I know that the most reasonable implementation for this function is `return o2` as `o1` and `o2` have the same keys. Consider this example a simplification of another, more sophisticated scenario.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that `bad` is *not* a key in `T`? Also note you can just use `(o1: T, o2: T): T`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not using `o1: T, o2: T` version because in my real code both types will be different (keeping the "same keys" constraint).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the inner workings of TS, but I can't see how TS should be able to determine that `bad` isn't valid, in the function definition alone. It only knows which objects are passed on callsites. OTOH it doesn't seem to be too unreasonable to expect that TS would throw an error regarding `bad` at those callsites if it is indeed not present in the arguments.

Comment: Good question, I don't know the answer. 
FYI `strictMerge<{a : string}>({a: "x"}, {a: "x"})` does not produce an error either.

Comment: Here is a list of known issues :
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38657
AND the main:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41237